# Webpack task on vsts build failing

Tags: webpack, azure-devops

Where am i missing the ")" ?

I am a bit confused and searches on stackoverflow and the web seems to only return non relevant information.

I am using this webpack extention [github](https://github.com/Dealogic/webpack-vsts-extension) and am running a asp.net core 2 angular template, the only thing i have added is @angular/material

and this is the setup:

[image]

What is happening here?

```
##[error]SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z C:\NPM\Modules\webpack:2
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z           ^^^^^^^
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7000981Z     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7010970Z     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-09-14T20:08:13.7010970Z     at Object.resolveWebpackModule (d:\a\_tasks\webpack_6752a610-c2f3-11e6-949e-5d3841f133f1\3.0.19\webpackModuleResolver\WebpackModuleResolver.js:6:11)
```

[image: Debug output from vsts]

Comment: Looks like you have a shell script containing `basedir=$(dirname blah blah)`  that webpack is trying to run as a javascript file.

Comment: I am using this extention https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dealogic.webpack-vsts-extension it askes for a webpack.config.js file

Comment: What's the result if you queue the build on private agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) which installed the webpack on the local machine?

Comment: Running on a private agent resulting in: "WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema." I am using the Asp.net core 2 angular templates and the webpack.config.js file

Comment: What's the detail code of webpack.config.js? How do you create asp.net core 2 angular project?

Comment: The project is created in VS2017 with the built in Angular core 2.0 template [webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/RoarG/4eeace17a5dda86d44881c51c4a0ccf9)

Answer (score 1):

Get the same behavior as you when install webpack globally.

The workaround is installing webpack locally in npm install task:
[image]
And then specify the local path where the webpack installed:
[image]